# xampp switching to localhost when loading wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

When I'm on the Xampp dashboard and go to my Wordpress folder (82...../wp(wp is the name of the folder))on a different pc than the host, it links me to localhost/wp. This obviously doesnt work. It works fine on my host PC obviously,
because localhost is the host server location. I port forwarded port 80, 443 and 3306. PhpMyAdmin works great. Im sure this is some setting in the WP config, but whatever I do in editing some of the files, it doesn't work. For now, I have set them back to default. Please help!

EDIT: Fixed by exporting the DB, replacing all localhost with my ip. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a lot of experience with Wordpress, but something like that happened to me a while ago and what I did was export the database, open it with a text editor and replace all occurrences of `http://localhost` with my IP [`http://192.168.0.10`] and then loading that file again

Don't forget to clear cache (or open it in incognito) after the change is done

Answer (score 0):

Look for these two parameters in your wp_config.php file.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Also, check your database in the wp_options table to see if your domain is set correctly.

Try to check this article: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL